# Which is minimum permission or role needed to store views in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam

we have some restrictions on our GCP prod instance that is why I cannot store BQ views there.
Do you know the minimum permission or role needed to store views in BigQuery?
Then I would take that into a discussion with our user administration.

Thank you,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

See this page: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions_and_predefined_roles for permissions and roles.

Here BigQuery view falls into the category of `table`, therefore, you'll need 
`bigquery.tables.create` permission to be able to store a view (and probably `bigquery.tables.update` to update the view definition later).

Predefined roles seems too wide, you might just ask admin to create a custom role for you. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles

And in case the dataset for holding tables is too sensitive, you could suggest admin to create a "view only" dataset and grant you enough permission or even assign you predefined role `roles/bigquery.dataEditor` to that dataset only.

Comment: thank you! So with this "view only" dataset I could create new views whenever I want without being able to create or update real tables? (Cause creating and updating BQ tables is for sure not permitted in my company.)

Comment: Yes. And it will be a logical "view only" dataset for there is no way for admin to allow you create view only. With tables.create, you will be able create both view and table in that dataset.